# How do i define array in shader's constant buffer with C#?

Tags: c#, hlsl, data-structure, sharpdx, slimdx

I am using SharpDX to render 3D graphics and i cannot get to work constant buffer in my shader since it contains an array. Currently it looks like this:

```
cbuffer cb0 : register(b0)
{
    matrix mWorld;
    matrix mView;
    matrix mProj;
    float4 vLightDir[2];
    float4 vLightColor[2];
    float4 vOutputColor;
}
```

But how to define a struct in C#, which will be correctly marshalled to such constant buffer in shader? In C# we don't have "excplicit" array initialization, e.g. this line of code i used in C++ will not work in C#:

```
struct cb0
{
  // ...
  Vector4 twos[2];// C#: Vector4[] twos;
// ...
}
```

I always set StructLayout option Pack=16 for my structs for alignment, but HOW to define such struct with C#? i have tried to define struct like this:

```
struct cb0_t//pack=16
        {
            public Matrix mWorld;
            public Matrix mView;
            public Matrix mProj;
            public Vector4 vLightDir0;
            public Vector4 vLightDir1;
            public Vector4 vLightColor0;
            public Vector4 vLightColor1;
            public Vector4 vOutputColor;
        }
```

Yes, it works with this, but this IS NOT COOL. Thank you, sorry for my english...

Comment: unsafe+fixed is not solution here, as using 'manual' write to stream. it's all awful.

Comment: Does Vector4[] twos = new Vector4[2] not work? That's strange, I guess.

Answer (score 1):

If you make a light structure and send that as an array it should work, also maybe use two constant buffers?

Looks something like this(HLSL):

```
struct Light
{
float4 vLightDir;
float4 vLightColor;
};
cbuffer Camera : register(b0)
{
matrix mWorld;
matrix mView;
matrix mProj;
}

cbuffer Lights : register(b1)
{
Light lights[];  
}
```

C#

```
[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
public struct Light
{
public Vector4 LightDir;
public Vector4 LightColor;
}
[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
public struct Camera
{
public Matrix mWorld;
public Matrix mView;
public Matrix mProj;
}
private Light[] lights = new Light[2] { };
private Buffer LightCB;

public void updatelight(DirectXDevice _dev)
{
lights(0) = new light();
lights(0).LightDir = new vector4();
lights(0).LightColor = new vector4();
lights(1) = new light();
lights(1).LightDir = new vector4();
lights(1).LightColor = new vector4();
LightCB = _dev.CreateBuffer(BindFlags.ConstantBuffer, lights);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you can use the `MarshalAs` attribute like so

```
[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential, Pack = 16)]
public struct cb0_t
{
    public Matrix mWorld;
    public Matrix mView;
    public Matrix mProj;
    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValArray, SizeConst=2)]
    public Vector4[] vLightDir;
    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValArray, SizeConst=2)]
    public Vector4[] vLightColor;
    public Vector4 vOutputColor;
}
```

You can take a look [at this article](http://timjones.tw/blog/archive/2011/03/08/marshalling-c-structures-into-directd-cbuffers-using), search for the heading Arrays.

Otherwise here's a [shorter solution on StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14629106/3303982).